# Expresión regular para mostrar el contenido de la etiqueta title

Tags: javascript, regex

Actulmente estoy realizando un proyecto pero no logro encontrar la expresión regular que me muestre el contenido de la etiqueta `title` de un HTML.
¿Me podrian ayudar?

Adjunto la expresión regular que estoy utilizando de momento :

```
 /¨[<title>]+[a-z]+[</title>]/g
```

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres ocupar una regex para dicha tarea?, nos compartirías además por favor un poco de lo que lleves hecho

Comment: hasta ahora la expresion que he creado es esta, /¨[<title>]+[a-z]+[</title>]/g

Comment: Es decir quieres el valor que esta entre las etiquetas `title` cierto?

Comment: Debido a que la base para este proyecto son las expresiones regualares

Comment: si, he intentado de varias maneras pero, me seleciona las demas etiquetas o lo que esta afuera de las etiquetas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero mas allá de la petición que no se requieren expresiones regulares para una tarea como la indicada, debería bastar con hacer algo como lo siguiente:

- Seleccionar la etiqueta `querySelector()` para obtener el primer elemento que coincida con el parámetro asignado
- Obten el texto por medio de la propiedad `text` del nodo recuperado que en este caso es la etiqueta `<title></title>`

Quedando de este modo:

```html
    <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    <script>
    
       let titulo = document.querySelector("title")
            
       console.log(titulo.text)
    
    </script>
```

**Referencias**

- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que me quedare con esta

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas usar una **expresion regular** para mostrar el contenido de una etiqueta title HTML, una expresion regular se usa para encontrar coincidencias de valores en una cadena por medio de una serie de reglas.

Aqui te dejo el link para informacion:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Te recomiendo usar este código que te muestra el contenido del `title HTML`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the title of the document.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.title;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a intentar

Answer (score 0):

Si bien como han dicho usar una expresión regular no es un buen camino obtener datos de html, la expresión regular podría ser algo como `(?!<title>)\w+(?=<\/title>)`, usando negative lookahead `(?!` y positive lookahead `(?=` :

```js
const html = `<div><title>titulo1</title><title>titulo2</title></div>`;

const contenido = html.match(/(?!<title>)\w+(?=<\/title>)/gi);

console.log(contenido);
```

Métodos como `querySelectorAll()` usan arboles y recursion para extraer los datos, son lógicas totalmente distintas a las regex y definitivamente estas últimas no son el camino para estos casos.